# Need help in using count in remote-exec provisioner to retrieve multiple VMs IPs

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to use count to install a package on 2 of my VMs using a single remote-exec provisioner. As of now, I am doing that individually in 2 provisioners blocks as below.

----present code to use remote provisioner for 2 vms-----

```
resource "null_resource" "install_nginx_host1" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt install nginx -y"
    ]
  }
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    host        = module.virtual-machine[0].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-0
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "install_nginx_host2" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt install nginx -y"
    ]
  }

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    host        = module.virtual-machine[1].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-1
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me in getting the value which I should should to set host using count.index? I tried multiple things e.g.
**host        = "module.virtual-machine[${count.index}].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-${count.index}"**

But it returns the host strings as:
module.virtual-machine[0].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-0
module.virtual-machine[1].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-1

while I want the value of above strings.

Comment: Have you tried using the interpolation syntax with quotes, i.e., `"${module.virtual-machine[1].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-1}"`?

Comment: Thanks Marko. I can refer the IPs of VM1 with "module.virtual-machine[0].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-0" and VM2 with "module.virtual-machine[1].linux_vm_public_ips.instance-1". I am looking for syntax with count.index so that I can reiterate both machines in a single remote-exec provisioner.

Comment: Can you add the `module.virtual_machine` code to the question as well?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with module.virtual_machine code now.

Comment: So the VMs are created without any errors? Because I don't see the `count` variable in the module documentation, only `instances_count`: https://github.com/kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-virtual-machine/blob/master/variables.tf#L120-L123.

Comment: Yes, 2 VMs with VM name "instance-0" and "instance-1" are created, can access both VMs with ssh to the public IPs.



$ tf console
> module.virtual-machine
[
  {
    "admin_ssh_key_private" = (sensitive)
    "admin_ssh_key_public" = null
    "linux_virtual_machine_ids" = [
      "/subscriptions/06ef8f72\/resourceGroups/rg-longhorn/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/instance-0",
      "",
    ]
    "linux_vm_password" = (sensitive)
    "linux_vm_private_ips" = {
      "instance-0" = "10.0.1.4"
    }
    "linux_vm_public_ips" = {
      "instance-0" = "20.x.x.x"
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward to achieve:

```
resource "null_resource" "install_nginx_host1" {
  count = 2
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt install nginx -y"
    ]
  }
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
    host        = module.virtual-machine[count.index].linux_vm_public_ips["instance-${count.index}"]
  }
}
```

Please make sure you understand how to use the `count` meta-argument [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count

Comment: Thank you Marko, it works. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be highly appreciated as well.